# Select distinct nodes and total amount from xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I have XML, which should be transformed by **XSLT 1.0**. XML folder "Fields" defines names order for every "Row" element. So, MaterialCode in every "Row" folder has first position,StorageMatCode is second and "Amount" is third. I need remove all "MaterialCode" duplicates, but put all "Amounts" in one. 
**Input xml:**

```
<Response xmlns="http://www.sample.ru/sample/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <ObjectType>StorageMats</ObjectType>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Fields>
        <Field type="decimal">MaterialCode</Field>
        <Field type="decimal">StorageMatCode</Field>
        <Field type="decimal">Amount</Field>
    </Fields>
</Header>
<Body>
    <Row>
        <FieldValue>475625947</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>456789</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>1000</FieldValue>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FieldValue>804685387</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>273456</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>3047</FieldValue>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FieldValue>973681347</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>578357</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>2037</FieldValue>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FieldValue>804685387</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>273456</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>5000</FieldValue>
    </Row>
</Body>
</Response>
```

**I want to get this XML:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BDStorageMats xmlns="http://www.sample.ru/sample/BDStorageMats/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BDStorageMat>
        <MaterialCode>475625947</MaterialCode>
        <Amount>1000</Amount>
    </BDStorageMat>
    <BDStorageMat>
        <MaterialCode>804685387</MaterialCode>
        <Amount>8047</Amount>
    </BDStorageMat>
    <BDStorageMat>
        <MaterialCode>973681347</MaterialCode>
        <Amount>2037</Amount>
    </BDStorageMat>
</BDStorageMats>
```

**I've created this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.sample.ru/sample/BDStorageMats/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:key match="*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Body']/*[local-name()= 'Row']" name="codeDistinct" use="*[local-name()= 'FieldValue'][count(*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Header']/*[local-name()= 'Fields']/*[local-name()= 'Field'][.='MaterialCode']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <BDStorageMats>
        <xsl:variable name="amountPosition" select="count(*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Header']/*[local-name()= 'Fields']/*[local-name()= 'Field'][.='Amount']/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="materialCodePosition" select="count(*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Header']/*[local-name()= 'Fields']/*[local-name()= 'Field'][.='MaterialCode']/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Body']/*[local-name()= 'Row'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('codeDistinct', *[local-name()= 'FieldValue'][count(*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Header']/*[local-name()= 'Fields']/*[local-name()= 'Field'][.='MaterialCode']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]))[1]]">
            <xsl:variable name="keyGroup" select="key('codeDistinct', *[local-name()= 'FieldValue'][count(*[local-name()= 'Response']/*[local-name()= 'Header']/*[local-name()= 'Fields']/*[local-name()= 'Field'][.='MaterialCode']/preceding-sibling::*)+1])"/>
            <BDStorageMat>
                <MaterialCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(*[local-name()= 'FieldValue'])[$materialCodePosition]"/>
                </MaterialCode>
                <Amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum($keyGroup/(*[local-name()= 'FieldValue'])[$amountPosition])"/>
                </Amount>
            </BDStorageMat>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </BDStorageMats>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it works fine in Altova, but my system uses Apache Xalan Processor for XSLT and it refuses this line from XSLT:

```
<Amount>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum($keyGroup/(*[local-name()= 'FieldValue']) [$amountPosition])"/>
</Amount>
```

Is there any other way to do what i want via XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Xalan (or another processor that supports the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function), you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.sample.ru/sample/"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="row" match="ns1:Row" use="ns1:FieldValue[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/ns1:Response">
    <BDStorageMats xmlns="http://www.sample.ru/sample/BDStorageMats/1.0">
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(ns1:Body/ns1:Row/ns1:FieldValue[1])">
            <BDStorageMat>
                <MaterialCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </MaterialCode>
                <Amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('row', .)/ns1:FieldValue[3])" />
                </Amount>
            </BDStorageMat>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </BDStorageMats>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the use of a prefix to select the nodes in the input XML correctly.